# How to open sqlite DB in onrestart()

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, illegalstateexception

I am updating home listview using data retrieved from DB. When I go forth then comeback to Home it crashes

My code is here

```
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestart called");
    DatabaseManager.getInstance(HomeActvity.this).open();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    DatabaseManager.getInstance(HomeActvity.this).closeDatabase();
}
```

My Log is:

```
11-28 19:07:22.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24303): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
11-28 19:07:22.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24303):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1224)
11-28 19:07:22.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24303):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
11-28 19:07:22.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24303):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
```

I tried runOnUIThread()..

Comment: Are you sure you closed the database onStop?

Comment: Display your whole activity code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you close your database right after notifydatachanged? I think database reading is happening after close. Try to remove the line and see if it's working.

```
DatabaseManager.getInstance(HomeActvity.this).open();
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

<strike>DatabaseManager.getInstance(HomeActvity.this).closeDatabase();</strike>

Comment: Without looking at more code, that was my best guess. Why don't you post your listAdapter code.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing in between open and close! how come..